# SSL errors on graph.windows.net

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I recently observed some SSL errors while trying to connect to https://graph.windows.net from a Java code. 
The errors are random but represent 1 error for 10 requests

Does someone has the same problem ?
It's possible to try by using the SSLPOKE utility
(https://gist.github.com/4ndrej/4547029)

Answer (score 3):

We are also getting this looking at a trace in curl (curl --trace foo.txt https://graph.windows.net) when it fails it looka as though the return certificate get truncated at the same place in the return

**Good Request**

```
== Info: Connected to graph.windows.net (104.41.216.30) port 443 (#0)
== Info: successfully set certificate verify locations:
== Info: SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
<= Recv SSL data, 4472 bytes (0x1178)
```

**Bad Request**

```
== Info: Connected to graph.windows.net (104.41.216.31) port 443 (#0)
== Info: successfully set certificate verify locations:
== Info: SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
<= Recv SSL data, 3051 bytes (0xbeb)

Failing on line
0be0: 2a c7 29 46 23 58 9f 01 0f 2a b2                *.)F#X...*.
```

Interestingly I have been testing this more and have found this IP graph.windows.net (104.41.216.31)  coming up more that once in a failed request. So not sure if that is a sick host

Answer (score 0):

I am also seeing the same problem in our PHP app since 2017-02-03 13:12:00GMT

Specifically the error is:

```
cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate.
```

Happens about once every 7-10 requests.

Answer (score 0):

They fixed it I think,

I had the same problem yesterday (06/02/2017) on two different servers:

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:504: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
```

And after doing some tests this morning it's not reproducible anymore.